# Coroutine frame seems to be prematurely marked as destroyed when using address sanitizer

Tags: c++, c++20, address-sanitizer, c++-coroutine

I am trying to write a small and simple coroutine library just to get a more solid understanding of C++20 coroutines. It seems to work fine, but when I compile with clang's adress sanitizer, it throws up on me.

I have narrowed down the issue to the following code example (available with compiler and sanitizer output at https://godbolt.org/z/WqY6Gd), but I still can't make any sense of it.

```cpp
// namespace coro = std::/std::experimental;

// inlining this suppresses the error
__attribute__((noinline)) void foo(int& i) { i = 0; }

struct task {
  struct promise_type {
    promise_type() = default;
    coro::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    coro::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void unhandled_exception() noexcept { std::terminate(); }
    void return_value(int v) noexcept { value = v; }
    task get_return_object() {
      return task{coro::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
    }
    int value{};
  };

  void Start() { return handle_.resume(); }
  int Get() {
    auto& promise = handle_.promise();
    return promise.value;
  }

  coro::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle_;
};

task func() { co_return 3; }

int main() {
  auto t = func();
  t.Start();
  const auto result = t.Get();
  foo(t.handle_.promise().value);
  // moving this one line down or separating this into a noinline 
  // function suppresses the error
  // removing this removes the stack-use-after-scope, but (rightfully) reports a leak
  t.handle_.destroy();
  if (result != 3) return 1;
}
```

Address sanitizer reports use-after-scope (full output available at godbolt, link above).
With some help from lldb, I found out that the error is thrown in main, more precisely: the jump at line 112 in the assembly listing, `jne .LBB2_15`, jumps to asan's report and never returns. It seems to be inside `main`'s prologue.

As the comments indicate, moving `destroy()` a line down or calling it in a separate noinline function<sup>1</sup> changes the behavior of address sanitizer. The only two explanations to this seem to be undefined behavior and asan throwing a false positive (or `-fsanitize=address` itself is creating lifetime issues, which is sort of the same in a sense).

At this point I'm fairly certain that there's no UB in the code above: both `task` and `result` live on main's stack frame, the promise object lives in the coroutine frame. The frame itself is allocated (on main's stack because no suspend-points) at line 1 of main, and destroyed right before returning, past the last access to it in `foo()`. The coroutine frame is not destroyed automatically because control never flows off `co_await final_suspend()`, as per [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11). I've been staring at this code for a while, though, so please forgive me if I missed something obvious.

The assembly generated without sanitation seems to makes sense to me and all the memory access happens within [rsp, rsp+24], as allocated. Futhermore, compiling with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`, or just `-fsanitize=undefined`, or simply compiling with gcc with `-fsanitize=address` reports no errors, which leads me to believe the issue is hidden somewhere in the code generated by asan.

Unfortunately, I can't quite make sense of what exactly happens in the code instrumented by asan, and that's why I'm posting this. I have a general understanding of [Address sanitizer's algorithm](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm), but I can't map the assembly memory access/allocations to what's happenning in the C
++ code.

I'm hoping that an answer will help me

1. Understand where the lifetime issues are hidden, if there are any
2. Understand what exactly happens in `main` when compiled with asan, so that a person reading this can have a more clear way of finding what memory access in the C++ code triggered the error, and where (if anywhere) was that memory allocated and freed.
3. Consistently suppress this particular false positive, and elaborate a bit on what causes it, if the issue really is in asan.

Thanks in advance.

---

<sup>1</sup> This initially lead me to believe that clang's optimizer is reading `result` from the (destroyed) coroutine's frame directly, but moving `destroy()` into task's destructor brings the issue back and proves that theory wrong, as far as I can tell. `destroy()` is not in the destructor in the listing above because it requires implementing move construction/assignment in order to avoid double free, and I wanted to keep the example as small and clear as possible.

Comment: a smaller/cleaner example: https://godbolt.org/z/d76xTa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out - but mostly because it's already fixed in clang12.0.

Running the [smaller/cleaner example](https://godbolt.org/z/d76xTa) with clang-12 shows no error from asan. The difference is in the following lines:

```
    movabs  rcx, -866669180174077455    
    mov     qword ptr [r13 + 2147450880], rcx   
    mov     dword ptr [r13 + 2147450888], -202116109    
    lea     rdi, [r12 + 40] 
    mov     rcx, rdi    
    shr     rcx, 3  
    cmp     byte ptr [rcx + 2147450880], 0  
    jne     .LBB2_14    
    lea     r14, [r12 + 32] 
    mov     qword ptr [r14 + 8], offset f() [clone .cleanup]    
    lea     rdi, [r14 + 16] 
    mov     byte ptr [r13 + 2147450884], 0  
    mov     rcx, rdi    
    shr     rcx, 3  
    mov     dl, byte ptr [rcx + 2147450880] 
    test    dl, dl  
    jne     .LBB2_7 
.LBB2_8:    
    mov     qword ptr [rbx + 16], rax       # 8-byte Spill  
    mov     dword ptr [r14 + 16], 0
```

Which clang-11 has, and clang-12 doesn't. From the looks of it, the address sanitizer tries to check that `r12+40` (which should be the promise's cleanup method) is initialized before initializing it.
Clang-12 just performs no checks for the promise, leaving the entirity of the code above out.

**TL;DR**: (probably) a bug in clang-11 coroutine sanitation, fixed in 12.0, perhaps in later versions of clang-11 as well.